# How can I clean residual config files with BleachBit app?

Tags: cleanup

I want to clean residual config files with `BleachBit` like Synaptic Package Manager can do this. Can I achieve it somehow?

There's a custom setting in `BleachBit` which allows to configure a specific path for cleaning, so where or can I point it to look for those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those package are just that has configuration files that hasn't been removed.

It will be exhausting to use bleachbit, those files are spread allover your system and not founded under same folder. So you have to search for these files of each package alone then send its path to bleachbit. This would be so exhausting and time consuming, so it's better to use this command from your terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge
```

You can get the list of the packages names that having residual config files by running the command:

```
grep-status -n -sPackage -FStatus config-files
```

Comment: Thanks! Will figure something out with your examples then.